# Geo intent to Google Maps with a Balloon

Tags: android, google-maps

Is it possible to launch a Google Maps window from my app that shows a specific position plus a balloon with a label that I can define?

This could be done with

```
geo:lat,lon?q=my_label
```

but with latest Google Maps it shows a marker on the position with no balloon attached to it, then on the bottom of the screen it reads "labeled as my_label". Can I circumvent this?